# What are the default values for extended slice with negative and positive step

Tags: python

What are the default values of start and stop in list slice? Do they change if the step is positive or negative?

For example:

```
 a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 print(a[::1]) 
 >>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Above code makes it look that default value of start and stop are 0 and len(a).

But if we use a step = -1

```
 a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 print(a[::-1]) 
 >>> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Following python documenttation from https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

> Slice indices have useful defaults; an omitted first index defaults to
>   zero, an omitted second index defaults to the size of the string being
>   sliced.

If that is the case we should get an empty list.

```
 a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 print(a[0:len(a):-1]) 
 >>> []

 a = "python"
 a[0:len(a):-1]
 >>>> ''
```

Comment: the answer is `None` and `None`. Let me find the exact duplicate of this (interesting) question (there are several duplicates actually)

Comment: @OP: `>>> a[None:None:-1]
; [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`

Comment: So you are saying slice function internally uses different defaults for start and stop which is dependent on sign of step?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I updated the question and I feel the tagged duplicate question does not answer it.

Comment: @2ank3th maybe it's not the proper duplicate, but there's another one. Let me dig (if someone can help I'd be glad)

Comment: @2ank3th bingo found the exact duplicate don't you agree?

Comment: yes it is!! Thanks @Jean